# Mapping polyline points to intrinsic dimension of image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg, coordinates

The polyline points are plotted against the viewBox value. But I need the existing points to translate according to the image dimension of 3700 x 790 
[image]
I am plotting the polylines on a rendered image of dimensions 1680 x 358
The natural dimensions of the image is 3700 x 790

The polyline points on the rendered images are:

> 501.9856872558594,142.00601196289062,440.98309326171875,11.000466346740723,376.9803771972656,52.00220489501953,297.9770202636719,136.00576782226562,280.976318359375,262.0111083984375,378.98046875,302.0127868652344,477.9846496582031,276.0116882324219

I want these points to be normalized and stored according to the natural dimensions of the image

Comment: use a viewBox to do the mapping.

Comment: I have used viewBox and its mapping it on the browser. I want the exact coordinates to be translated on the actual image

Comment: The image on which I am plotting the polylines is a downscaled image and is rendered according to the width of the window I am working in.

The polyline points are plotted according to the rendered dimensions.

I want the polyline points on the rendered image to correspond to the actual image size.

Comment: Cause I am plotting the polylines using d3.js

Comment: Please tell the details you need to provide me a solution

Comment: I think we'll need a [mcve] here. Please edit the question to add one.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Please check

Comment: A screenshot is not a [mcve]

Comment: I would like to understand why the images have a different aspect ratio. You are using an image of  3700 x 790 as an image of 1680 x 358